# Number of different factors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If $n+1$ numbers $a, b, c, d, ...$ be all different, and each of them a prime number, prove that the number of different factors of the expression $a^mbcd ...$ is $(m+1)2^n-1$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Shouldn't it be $(m+1)2^n$?  or are you counting only *proper* factors?

Comment: I don't know brother

Comment: Nothing extra is mentioned

Comment: Take a simple example:  $n=1$, $a=2$, $b=3$, $m=2$.  $12$ has $3\times2$ factors:  $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, $ and $12$

Comment: I think you are correct, there may be some error in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try building every possible factor by going through every prime $a,b,\dots$ and asking yourself the following question : how many times do I want this prime to appear in my factor? Can you complete the proof with this idea?